# Как реализовать условный рендеринг в функциональном компоненте React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, render, prerender

Всем доброго времени суток!

Хочу реализовать условный рендеринг в функциональном React-компоненте. Не знаю как это сделать в функции.

Мне нужно, чтоб в зависимости от состояния рендерился соответствующий импортированный компонент.

Я написал эту логику с помощью тернарного оператора, и всё работает, но этот код ужасный и нечитабельный.

Мне обязательно нужно реализовать это именно в функциональном компоненте, т.к. использую Хуки.

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

import Header from './header/header';
import Footer from './footer/footer';

//Один из этих компонентов будет рендерится между Хэдером и Футером  ↓
//Название компонента в состоянии (activeItem)

import Landing from './landing/landing';
import BookingManagement from './bookingManagement/BookingManagement';
import BookingTickets from './bookingTickets/bookingTickets';
import EnterProfile from './enterProfile/enterProfile';
import PersonalArea from './personalArea/personalArea';
import Register from './register/register';
import SearchResults from './searchResults/searchResults';
import ChoosePlace from './choosePlace/choosePlace';


function App() {
    
    const [activeItem, setActiveItem] = useState('landing');
    
    
     useEffect(() => {
        console.log(activeItem)
      });

  return (
       <>
      
      
          <Header changeMain={setActiveItem}/>
            
      
    
       {(activeItem=='landing' ? (
        <Landing changeMain={setActiveItem}/>
      ) : (
        <></>
      ))}
        {(activeItem=='bookingManagement' ? (
        <BookingManagement />
      ) : (
        <></>
      ))}
          {(activeItem=='bookingTickets' ? (
        <BookingTickets />
      ) : (
        <></>
      ))}
        {(activeItem=='enterProfile' ? (
                <EnterProfile />
              ) : (
                <></>
         ))}
          {(activeItem=='personalArea' ? (
                <PersonalArea />
              ) : (
                <></>
         ))}
           {(activeItem=='register' ? (
                <Register/>
              ) : (
                <></>
         ))}
             {(activeItem=='searchResults' ? (
                <SearchResults/>
              ) : (
                <></>
         ))}

           {(activeItem=='choosePlace' ? (
                <ChoosePlace />
              ) : (
                <></>
         ))}
          
          
          
          
          
          
      
          <Footer changeMain={setActiveItem}/>
       </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Боже.. За что ты так людей ненавидишь? =(

1. Эффекты НЕЛЬЗЯ оставлять без группировки.

```js
useEffect(() => {
        console.log(activeItem)
      }, [activeItem]);
```

2. Ответ на твой вопрос. В чём сладость функционального программирования, в том что функции могут быть в функциях и им это не мешает им жить дружно. **Главное этим не злоупотреблять**.

```js
function getItem() {
  switch (activeItem) {
    case 'landing': return <Landing changeMain={setActiveItem}/>;
    case 'bookingManagement': return <BookingManagement />;
    ...
    default: return null;
  }
}


  return (<>
      <Header changeMain={setActiveItem}/>
      { getItem() }
      <Footer />
     </>)
```